# Old time bike. Can I put a rear derailleur?

Tags: derailleur-rear

[image]

Hi guys,
I am looking to build up an old timer bike and I have found this frame. Can I put a rear derailleur in that socket?

Comment: It has a derailleur hanger, so why not?  (And it's not *that* old.)

Comment: (But note that, unless you have access to a pile of spare parts, it would be cheaper to buy a new bike.)

Comment: I am full of spare parts!!!

Comment: My main concern is that it has horizontal dropouts so the set up must be singlespeed or fixed... I am a little bit confused...

Comment: For a single speed setup you need adjustable horizontal dropouts (with a long slot).  There is no similar requirement for a derailleur setup, since the derailleur takes up the slack.

Comment: (Note that there are multiple chainrings, so it's always had a derailleur setup.)

Comment: Some (unsolicited) remarks.  I suspect this bike was originally built up as randonneur bicycle or some kind of commuter bike.  There are two things quite striking about the setup: firstly the handlebar stem. It doesn't look like a stem used originally on a Peugeot to me.  More something used on a "Dutch" town bike.  Secondly the  brakes: these are cantilever brakes.  In the past used on mountain bikes and cyclocross bikes (for wider tires and mud clearance).  Cantilever brakes require the same cable pull as modern road calliper brakes, but different from more modern mountain bike v-brakes.

Comment: On second look, I spotted the brake levers I hadn't seen at first.  Those are flat bar brake levers and I assume match the pull needed for the cantilever brakes (since they are already connected!)
Are you intended to build this up as a flat bar or drop bar bicycle?

Comment: @Agamemnon correction - that type of rear dropout is almost horizontal but does not require singlespeed or fixed.  You're confusing horizontal dropouts with trackends, which are not even classed as dropouts.

Comment: @Agamemnon Dropouts used to be angled like that. Horizontal ones are literally horizontal.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that is a standard derailleur hanger. Before attaching a derailleur, make sure that the hanger is aligned straight. There are tools to do this, but you can usually tell by eye if it's out of alignment. On a steel frame like that one, you can typically bend the hanger back into alignment with no problems. Also check that the threads are not stripped. If the threads are damaged, you may be able to use a thread tap to clean them up, or in the worst case, insert a helicoil. If you're not familiar with a helicoil, search "rear derailleur hanger helicoil" for examples. They will usually come with instructions for installation.

With regard to the dropouts, horizontal dropouts were standard on bicycles for many decades, whether they were single-speed or multi-geared. Look at pretty much any picture of a bike from before the late 80's. The only difference from a vertical dropout frame is that you have to pay a bit more attention to aligning the wheel properly in the frame when you put it on. Check that the wheel is properly positioned with respect to the brake pads and that the rim is equidistant from the chainstays. From your picture, though, it appears that the dropouts on this frame have stops in them, so that you can simply pull the wheel back against the stops. If they are set up correctly, the wheel should be aligned properly when seated against them.

Comment: Thanks Andrew for your detailed answer. I was confused because the guy that sells this frame has a title like: Peugeut Rennrad fixie singlespeed rahmen retro. Thanks again.

Comment: The seller is just putting all keywords they can think of to maximize search hits. This isn't a racing bike ("rennrad") either but a touring bike.

Comment: @ojs - If it were a true touring bike it would have doubled eyelets, to accommodate both fenders and racks.

Comment: Dropouts of this kind need alignment screws for the rear axle. Look at the rear end of the dropouts. There's probably a 3mm thread in each. These screws make sure that the axle sits in the correct position when you put back the wheel to avoid fiddling at wheel changes.

Comment: @carel They don’t _need_ alignment screws. Typically only higher end frames had them. My ‘84 Schwinn World Sport, for example, does not have any. You just align the wheel by hand before tightening the axle nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem as the frame/bike originally came with a rear derailleur. Since the frame is steel, you can spread the rear dropouts to accommodate just about any width rear hub out there. There are many articles on the web on how to do this. Just make sure that the chain, derailleur and freewheel/freehub match in respect to speeds! You should be fine with any narrow six, seven and eight speed group of components as they are all pretty much the same width. If you run an older five speed chain, then the freewheel and cluster must match as those chains are a little wider, the same for a ten plus speed as they are narrower. I have run nine speed derailleurs with eight speed clusters and nine speed chainrings with eight speed derailleurs with good results without having to shim the jockey wheels or the chainrings. I have a bunch of steel bikes dating back to the late sixties and yours is definitely worth saving.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Thank you guys for your info and everything. The first bike was a little bit strange with the brakes, rear dropouts and all this stuff so I found another one. Road bike, 57cm, 2×6 speed. I'll start by putting a flat bar, flat bar brake levers and that's it. Later I'll try to put a 9 or 10 cassette.